# stuck fermentation/lowering acidity

Tags: wine, fruit, stuck-fermentation, acidity

I am having trouble getting a batch of wine off the ground. Its a three gallon batch of Lemon wine and fermentation just wont start. My SG is 1.09, temp is stable at 75, acidity is at 3.0 using those color changing test strips. Using RedStar champagne yeast

My guess is that my acidity is to high for the yeast

What are the best ways to lower acidity of my must?

Answer (score 1):

Add some boiled Bicarbonate of Soda, that will drop the Ph, start with one tsp in about 50ml. Aim to get the Ph to around a bit above 4 and then you should be OK.